# Android - Force activity into portrait on phones only

Tags: android, android-orientation

EDIT: I'm putting this edit above because I think my question needed rephrasing.

I have a line in my mainfest for a certain scene below:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

This locks the scene into portrait.  What I needed was a way to unlock it programmatically in java, and the usual way did not appear to be working.  My code block below was actually correct, I had just had incorrect code elsewhere that was preventing it from working.

---

I'm wondering if there is a way to force a specific activity into portrait when it is on a phone, while still allowing it to be either portrait or landscape when it is on a tablet or any other larger device?

My situation is a little more complicated than most similar ones, however, because the activity I'm working with inherits from another activity class which I cannot change.  For some reason, the other activity will crash if onCreate() is called from a phone, so I can't just use "setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);" in onCreate() because the app still crashes when super.onCreate() is called.

I've tried locking the activity to portrait in the manifest and then adding this to onCreate:

```
if(!mIsPhone)
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
    }
```

This, however, doesn't do anything.  The scene remains locked into portrait on tablets.

Comment: Can you able to post full code for onCreate() ?

Answer (score 3):

First you can find out whether the device is a phone or tablet using the following:

```
public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
        & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
        >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}
```

After finding that set orientation by:

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```